# Upload to aws s3 using cli without folder path

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'd like to upload a `file.txt` on aws s3 that is located in something like `main/part1/part2/file.txt`, where `part1` and `part2` are unknown (those folders always change).
I can do that with the command `aws s3 cp ./main s3://mybucket --exclude "*" --include "*.txt" --recursive`, but then in my bucket I have the file located in `part1/part2/file.txt`. I'd like `file.txt` to be at the base of the bucket, not inside `part1/part2`

Is that possible given that `part1` and `part2` are constantly changing?

Comment: You might have to script this. You could do something like `find . -type f "*.txt"` within a shell script to get the list of files, and use `basename` to convert `main/part1/part2/file.txt` to `file.txt` to use as the S3 object key. Then execute `aws s3 cp` against each result.

Comment: Ahhh okay, that sounds like a promising solution! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for dir1 in $(ls main); do
    for dir2 in $(ls main/$dir1); do
        aws s3 cp ./main/$dir1/$dir2/ s3://my-bucket --exclude "*" --include "*.txt" --recursive
    done
done
```

```
upload: main/part1/part2/file.txt to s3://my-bucket/file.txt
upload: main/part11/part22/file2.txt to s3://my-bucket/file2.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

The following will work if `main` will never contain more than 1 subdirectory at a time (`part1`) & that subdirectory in-turn will never contain more than 1 subdirectory at a time (`part2`):

```
aws s3 cp ./main/*/*/ s3://my-bucket --exclude "*" --include "*.txt" --recursive
```

```
upload: main/part1/part2/file.txt to s3://my-bucket/file.txt
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing! Thanks! :D